# iOS clear layer of UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, sdk, layer

I drew a few lines in the layer property of my `UIView`.
But is there a method to clean up all the lines I drew?

I want to clear everything that is drawn on layer of my view.

I draw a line with the following code:

```
- (void)drawLine :(UIView *)drawInView :(CGPoint)startPosition :(CGPoint)endPosition
{
    //draw the line
    linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    lineShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    lineShape.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    lineShape.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;;
    lineShape.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

    CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, NULL, startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, endPosition.x, endPosition.y);

    lineShape.path = linePath;
    CGPathRelease(linePath);
    [drawInView.layer addSublayer:lineShape];
}
```

I found some code to remove all the sublayers I drew.

```
-(void)clearGraph :(UIView *)viewToClear
{
    for (CALayer *layer in viewToClear.layer.sublayers) {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
```

But this will give an Exception:

```
2013-08-28 21:10:18.877 ServerInfo[12861:3f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <CALayerArray: 0x1f86b3b0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x336ef3e7 0x3b3ea963 0x336eeec1 0x13f7d 0x158bb 0x340082fb 0x336c4857 0x336c4503 0x336c3177 0x3363623d 0x336360c9 0x33f5a5c3 0x33ffdc45 0x15843 0x34007231 0x3b8370e1 0x3b836fa8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I call my drawline method inside a NSTread. (doParsing method to be specific).

```
NSThread *myThread =[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callTimer) object:nil];
    [myThread start];

- (void)callTimer
{
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(doParsing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [runLoop run];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call `CGContextClearRect` with the current context and the rect to clear.

---

Based on your updated code, you aren't actually drawing anything. You're actually adding sub layers. So, to remove any previous line you need to remove the sub layer. You will need to come up with a way of finding the appropriate sub layer (maybe hold a property, maybe by tag) and then you can remove it just like you add it.

---

Don't perform the loop yourself, get the array to do it:

```
[viewToClear.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
```

Comment: Hi, Thx for you answer. I updated my question with the method I use to draw a line. Can you tell me what my context is in this case?

Comment: Thx for your answer you opened my eyes. I created a for loop that clears each layer but then I get an error <CALayerArray: 0x1f092260> was mutated while being enumerated.' This probably happens because I add a new line right after clearing it. Any Ideas?

Comment: If you are looping over an array you can't change it. Take a copy of the array and iterate over that.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I updated my code, maybe it helps you to understand what I'm doing, thx.

Comment: Why are you doing this on a background thread? All UI updates must be made on the main thread.

Comment: Hi, I'm creating a line graph, I do not want my app to hang thats why I use a thread. But I solved my problem by adding reverseObjectEnumerator.

Answer (score 15):

A much simpler way to remove all the sublayers of a UIView is to set its sublayers property to nil

```
viewToClear.layer.sublayers = nil;
```

Answer (score 4):

I used something very similar to Erwan's response..  but it turned out I didn't need the 'layer' part.  Here is what worked for me.  Small but effective.

`imageLayer.sublayers = nil;`

Answer (score 0):

For some people it may crash you just need to do this

```
2019-09-14 00:43:35.388050+0300 SummonersRift[17980:616553] [View] View has lost track of its superview, most likely through unsupported use of CALayer API on the view's layer. If this isn't a crash yet, it will be in the near future. 
    Problem view: <UIButton: 0x7f9c2491c7a0; frame = (54 54; 42 42); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002a16860>>
    Expected parent: <UIView: 0x7f9c24918db0; frame = (0 0; 150 150); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002a16840>>
Break on UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain to debug.
2019-09-14 00:43:35.388453+0300 SummonersRift[17980:616553] [LayoutConstraints] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
    Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000009f65d0 UIButton:0x7f9c2491c7a0.centerX == UIView:0x7f9c24918db0.centerX   (active)>
    Container hierarchy: 
<UIView: 0x7f9c24918db0; frame = (0 0; 150 150); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002a16840>>
    View not found in container hierarchy: <UIButton: 0x7f9c2491c7a0; frame = (54 54; 42 42); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002a16860>>
    That view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
2019-09-14 00:43:35.401892+0300 SummonersRift[17980:616553] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000009f65d0 UIButton:0x7f9c2491c7a0.centerX == UIView:0x7f9c24918db0.centerX   (active)> view:<UIView: 0x7f9c24918db0; frame = (0 0; 150 150); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002a16840>>'
*** First throw call stack:
```

To Fix this

```
    while let subview = draw_view.subviews.last {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    self.draw_view.layer.sublayers = nil
```